# Find the matrix transformation of a linear transformation $T: M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The problem states the following: Find the matrix transformation of a linear transformation $T: M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where
$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\d & c\end{bmatrix}\right)=a+b$.

My solution:
Using the canonical basis of $\beta=\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\}$, we can find the following:
$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)=1=1 \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)=1= 0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+1\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)=0=0 \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)=0=0 \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

From here we get that $[T]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Did I interpret the problem correctly and is this the correct solution?

Comment: It is not correct. Notice that target vector space is ${\bf R}$ and it is not $M_{2}({\bf R})$. Anyway the idea is correct.

Comment: $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is four-dimensional while $\mathbb R$ is one-dimensional. The matrix representation of $T$ should therefore be a $1\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: @A.P. should I edit it with a correct answer (just add it below this attempt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of matrix representation it is as follows: Suppose that $T: V\to W$ is a linear transformation between finite vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Consider the ordered basis $\beta_1=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $\beta_{2}=\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ basis of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Then, the matrix of representation of $T$ can be find as $$[T]_{\beta_{1}\to \beta_{2}}:=\begin{bmatrix}\uparrow& \cdots&\uparrow\\ [T(v_1)]_{\beta_2}&\cdots&[T(v_n)]_{\beta_2}\\\downarrow&\cdots&\downarrow\end{bmatrix}$$
That is each column of $[T]_{\beta_1\to \beta_2}$ is the coordinates $[T(v_k)]_{\beta_2}$ respect to the ordered basis $\beta_2$.

Here is your slight confusion, by using the same base for $M_{2}({\bf R})$ for ${\bf R}$ and noticed that it doesn't make sense. But you can fix it using $\beta_{2}=\{1\}$ as a basis for ${\bf R}$ and then.
$$[T]_{\beta_1\to \beta_2}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\in M_{1\times 4}({\bf R}).$$